# RabbitMQ consume local queue but publish to remote queue?

Tags: c#

I have an application which I want to consume messages from a local queue. However, this application is also required to publish messages to a remote queue.

I first create my factory and connection:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = hostname, UserName = "test", Password = "test" };
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

I then pass the connection to another class which builds the required channel and queues.

My question is, do I need to create two connections here? (1 for the local queue and 1 for the remote queue)

Or, can I specify in the `Send()` method a remote `RoutingKey`?

e.g:

```
channel.BasicPublish(
            exchange: "",
            routingKey: some.remote.ip.address:1234,
            basicProperties: props,
            body: SerializationUtils.Serialize(message));
```

Comment: "do I need to create two connections here"   Need is a strong word, but I would use 2 anyway to keep it cleaner.

Comment: @Davesoft Thanks - do you know if there will be any performance (eg latency) concessions with that approach?

Comment: It will not affect the performance if you take care of connections. You need to make sure that connections are not stay persisted otherwise it will end up with some heartbeat exceptions as per my experience.

Comment: @KeyurRamoliya Alright, thanks. My connections, channels and queues all get torn down on application exit.

Comment: @pookie That's perfect.